# How do i prove this? (I'm not sure what exactly the title should ne)

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $R=\prod_{i=1}^n [0,a_i]$ and $Q=\prod_{i=1}^n [c_i,d_i]$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be an orthogonal operator and $x=(c_1,...,c_n)$

Say, $Q\subset T(R)$.

How do i prove that $x+ T(-x+Q)\subset T(R)$?

And what is the subject studying questions like this precisely? (That is, geometry is not precise literally in modern mathematics framework)

Comment: Can you do the case when $Q$ is a single point?

Comment: @GEdgar I edited my post :)

Comment: I don't think this is true, because $[-1,0]\subset T([0,1])$ but $-1+-([-1,0]+1)=[-2,-1]\not\subset[-1,0]$ (with $T(x)=-x$).

Comment: Yes, i thought it would be true but it is not! Here's my question again : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639659/how-do-i-prove-that-sum-of-volumes-of-disjoint-rectangles-in-an-oblique-rectangl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this case: $n=1$, $R = [0,1]$, $Q=[-1,0]$, $x=-1$, and orthogonal operator is $T(u)=-u$ for all $u$.

Comment: thank you! Actually i posted this question since i thought it would be a lemma for another theorem i was going to prove. Would you please see my upcoming post? I will post it right now

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639659/how-do-i-prove-that-sum-of-volumes-of-disjoint-rectangles-in-an-oblique-rectangl