# How do I prove a bound on the sum of volumes of disjoint rectangles in an oblique rectangle?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

> Before I start, let's not assume anything about volume, since it is not precise unless Lebesgue measure is defined.

Let $\mathscr{B}=\{\prod_{i=1}^n [a_i,b_i)\subset \mathbb{R}^n:a_i\le b_i\}$ (That is, it is the set of half-open rectanges.)

Let's say $\mu(\prod_{i=1}^n [a_i,b_i))=\prod_{i=1}^n |b_i - a_i|$ for all element in $\mathscr{B}$.

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be an *orthogonal* operator.

Let $A\in \mathscr{B}$ and $\{A_k\}_{1≦k≦m}$ be a *mutually disjoint* finite sequence in $\mathscr{B}$.

Let's assume $\bigcup_{1≦k≦m} A_k \subset T(A)$.

> How do I prove that $\mu(\bigcup_{1≦k≦m} A_k) \le \mu(A)$?

Comment: Moreover, if this cannot be proven in short, please please recommend me a good text which treats this *precisely*

Comment: Maybe consult "A concise introduction to the Theory of Integration" by Daniel Stroock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be used to show that Lebesgue measure is invariant under orthogonal transformation.  So (as Mario noted) this is in the textbooks.

Probably I would prove a more general thing first, for linear transformation $T$ not necessarily orthogonal,
$$
\mu(T(A)) \le |\det T|\;\mu(A)
\tag{1}$$
and then for orthogonal $T$ observe that $|\det T| = 1$.  And for (1), first do it in case $T$ is an elementary row operation, since Gaussian reduction shows that general $T$ can be written as a finite composition of these.  But even that requires some work.